# How to create Virtual COM ports

Tags: serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I am trying to implement a software [Null Modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem).

Any suggestion how to create virtual COM Ports?

Looking for tips, strategy, known techniques, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the open-source [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) on windows for this before, and it worked well.  The related com2tcp project was more challenging to get working reliably.

Comment: I've downloaded the com0com code and don't see a project.  Is there one out there?   I love the way code project does it.. A complete project, build ready.